# Function decorator not being invoked

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, python-decorators

This has been driving me crazy because it should be so simple, but there must be some Python quirk I'm missing. I have a decorator that I'm trying to apply to a Flask route, but for some reason none of the decorators in my views.py seem to be getting loaded.

**decorators.py**

```
def admin_required(func):
    """Require App Engine admin credentials."""
    @wraps(func)
    def decorated_view(*args, **kwargs):
        if users.get_current_user():
            if not users.is_current_user_admin():
                abort(401)  # Unauthorized
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return redirect(users.create_login_url(request.url))
    return decorated_view
```

**views.py**

```
@admin_required
@blueprint.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

The `admin_required` decorator function is not being called (index.html is loaded without a redirect), and I cannot figure out why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: change the order of the decorators; `blueprint.route` only "sees" your undecorated function.

Decorators are applied inside-out, in loose analogy to function calls. Thus your function definition is equivalent to:

```
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
index = blueprint.route('/')(index)
index = admin_required(index)
```

Note how `blueprint.route` is passed the `index` function before it gets wrapped by `admin_required`. Of course, `admin_required` does eventually get applied to the `index` name in the module, so if you were to *call* `index` directly, it would go through both decorators. But you're not calling it directly, you're telling flask's request processor to call it.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it was something simple (although I'm kind of embarrassed I didn't try that already).